# How to show error message depends on other fields in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have two Drop down boxes, Hours and Minutes.
Hours has value start from "-",1,2,3....to 24.
Minutes has value start from "-",00,05,....to 60.
The default value for both fields is "-".

My Question is after clicking Save Button, want to show error message when Hours fields is not equal to "-", and user doesn't select Minutes field.

I tried validation rules such as required, required_if, required_with.
That didn't work.

```html
//create.blade.php

<select class="" name="hours" id="hours">
  @foreach ($hour_lists as $key => $hour_list)
    <option value="{{$hour_list}}"           @if(old('hours')==$hour_list) selected @end if>{{$hour_list}}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
Hours
<select class="" name="minutes" id="minutes">
  @foreach ($minutes_lists as $key => $minutes_list)
     <option value="{{$minutes_list}}" @if(old('minutes')==$minutes_list) selected @endif>{{$minutes_list}}</option>
  @endforeach
     </select>Minutes

<div class="form-group" @if(!empty($errors-> first('minutes'))) has-error @endif>
  <span class="help-block" style="color:red">       {{$errors->first('minutes')}} </span>
</div>
```

Comment: try regeX `/^\d+$/` . this will allow only numbers, so when you try to submit, the regeX validation wont allow

Comment: you can also use jquery validator add method.
Please refer https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote following code in ValidationRequest.

```
 public function getValidatorInstance()
 {
    $v = parent::getValidatorInstance();

    $v->sometimes(['hh','mm'],'numeric', function($input) {
         return $input->hh<> '-' or $input->mm<> '-';
    });
    return $v;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't send '-' as default value to server, instead of that, don't send if user didn't select anything or send empty value. And on Laravel side, you can use validation rules for that.

```
'hours' => 'nullable|date_format:H',
'minutes' => ['required_with:hours', 'date_format:i',
    function($attribute, $value, $fail) {
        if (! ($value % 5) == 0) {
            $fail('minute should be multiples of 5.')
        }
    }
],
```

---

**Update 29.08**

Ok, you have default value as `-`. You can write custom closure or create an array for rules and add rules as dynamically. An example, add `'minutes' => 'date_format:i'` if hours field is not equal to `-`.

Custom closure

```
'hours' => 'min:0|max:24',
'minutes' => ['min:0', 'max:60',
    function($attribute, $value, $fail) {
        if ($this->hours != '-' and $value == '-') {
            $fail(__('validation.required_with', ['values' => 'hours']));
        }
    }
]
```

Conditional

```
$rules = [
    // other rules
];

if ($this->hours != '-') {
    $rules['hours'] = 'date_format:H';
    $rules['minutes'] = 'date_format:i';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
But I need following.

if (hours <> "-" and minutes == "-"){
  show error message  => "Please input Minutes"
}

It is simple, but I don't know how to write in Laravel.

Comment: @Hayato updated my answer. is this validation enough?

Comment: Thanks for your updated answer.  date_format:i is good idea.
but, I want error message only user select Hours field.
As your code, the error is displayed even user doesn't select Hours field.
The problem is default value "-". but I can't remove it because of my customer needs.

Comment: @Hayato ok, you can write custom validation. I added some examples. You can edit these according to your need. I hope this can help to you. If not, we can find another solution.